# Obtaining partial decay constants from Gamow factors?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Consider the nuclide $^{190}\text{Pt}$, which is an alpha emitter.  By using the Gamow calculation [described here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/nuclear/alpdec.html), I am able to obtain a rough approximation of the decay constant $\lambda$ for this decay channel.   In addition I can calculate various theoretical two-body spontaneous fission branches for $^{190}\text{Pt}$ and use a similar calculation to obtain Gamow factors for them as well; obviously the likelihoods of these branches are vanishingly small.

Assuming two-body fissions are the only possibilities, is there a straightforward way to get from the Gamow factors $G_1\ldots G_{n}$ calculated above for the theoretical fission branches to partial decay constants $\lambda_{1} \ldots \lambda_{n}$ that can be used to calculate the partial activities $A_{i} = \lambda_{i}N_0$?  I understand that the Gamow factors provide the relative probabilities for each branch, but I am having difficulty tracking down a more concrete relation that will yield the partial decay constants. I could continue the Gamow calculation to its conclusion for these daughters as well, but I wonder whether the rest of the calculation is applicable.

Comment: Hi Eric. Perhaps I have not understood your question, but aren't the partial decay constants you are asking about also derived in the link?

Comment: @sammygerbil: the decay constants are indeed derived in that link for alpha decay.  One question is whether the same calculation is suitable for fission involving much larger fragments?  Perhaps it is.  I had assumed it might not be, or that the question should at any rate be posed before assuming that the calculation is suitable.